# Openning all text file & getting a string in python

Tags: python

How can I open all the text file within a folder and get a string ?
For example this is all the word in a txt file:

```
HelloWorld 
Hi 
HelloUser.
```

I want to get all the word with a `Hello` in the word and store it in an `array`.

I want to store it in an array not to return if its true or not.

Comment: How do you know which part you want?

Comment: Normally, you want to get a list of filenames—e.g., with `os.listdir`—and then loop over them: `words = []` `for filename in filenames:` `with open(filename) as file:` `for line in file:` `if <something>: words.append(<something else>)`.

Comment: As a side note, you probably want to store your words in a list. An `array` (whether a stdlib `array.array` or a third-party library like `numpy.array`) is usually use for a large collection of fixed-size values, not a collection of strings you build up one at a time.

Comment: I just want to append all the word that starts with hello in an array

Comment: The one this guy eyllanesc marked as duplicated isn't an answer to my question since it can only print a value. How can I store it in an array? I'm very new to python